# Parameters of Mutable struct same type as the struct

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a mutable struct Neuron with a parameter inputs which is of type vector of Neuron. Is this possible in Julia.
Following is what I am doing.

```
mutable struct Neuron
inputs::Vector{Neuron}
weights::Vector{Float64}
func::Function
output::Float64
#= parameters::Vector{Float64} =#
end
```

I am using julia 1.0. The error:
ERROR: LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant Neuron

Comment: Yeah, you can do that with Julia.  Checkout the [Inner Constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/manual/constructors/#Inner-Constructor-Methods-1) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-referential types are possible in Julia, as demonstrated in the Julia doc here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization-1

The idea is that you use [inner constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors/#Inner-Constructor-Methods-1) and the `new()` constructor to create an incompletely initialized Neuron first and then use it to create other Neurons.

```
mutable struct Neuron
  inputs::Vector{Neuron}
  # forgetting about the other fields for a second
  Neuron() = new()
  # or alternatively Neuron() = begin (x=new(); x.inputs = [x]; x) end
end
```